# android studio: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-api, android-geofence

I am trying to build a geofencing app using Kotlin in the android studio
but the VM crashed then the next run show this error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.mapgis, PID: 3002
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
> at com.example.mapgis.MapsActivity.onMapReady$lambda-2(Unknown Source:7)
> at com.example.mapgis.MapsActivity.$r8$lambda$j524CuJ2hJLTFNPmiaC5VRpPy0I(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.example.mapgis.MapsActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
> at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.0:1)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

the code

```
package com.example.mapgis

import android.Manifest
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.job.JobInfo
import android.app.job.JobScheduler
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Color
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.app.JobIntentService
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.mapgis.GeofenceReceiver
import com.example.mapgis.R
import com.example.mapgis.Reminder
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.CancellationToken
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import java.io.Serializable
import kotlin.random.Random

const val GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 200
const val GEOFENCE_ID = "REMINDER_GEOFENCE_ID"
const val GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION = 10 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 10 days
const val GEOFENCE_DWELL_DELAY =  10 * 1000 // 10 secs // 2 minutes
const val GEOFENCE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 12345
const val CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL = 13f
const val LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 123
private val TAG: String = MapsActivity::class.java.simpleName

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

        if (!isLocationPermissionGranted()) {
            val permissions = mutableListOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                permissions.toTypedArray(),
                LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return
            }
            this.map.isMyLocationEnabled = true

            // Zoom to last known location
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it != null) {
                    with(map) {
                        val latLng = LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude)
                        moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL))
                    }
                } else {
                    with(map) {
                        moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                LatLng(65.01355297927051, 25.464019811372978),
                                CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        setLongClick(map)
        setPoiClick(map)
    }

    private fun setPoiClick(map: GoogleMap) {
        map.setOnPoiClickListener { poi ->
            map.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(poi.latLng)
                    .title(poi.name)
            ).showInfoWindow()

//            scheduleJob()
        }
    }

    private fun setLongClick(map: GoogleMap) {
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener { latlng ->

            map.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                    .title("Current location")
            ).showInfoWindow()
            map.addCircle(
                CircleOptions()
                    .center(latlng)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70, 70, 70))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(70, 150, 150, 150))
                    .radius(GEOFENCE_RADIUS.toDouble())
            )
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, CAMERA_ZOOM_LEVEL))

            val database = Firebase.database
            val reference = database.getReference("reminders")
            val key = reference.push().key
            if (key != null) {
                val reminder = Reminder(key, latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)
                reference.child(key).setValue(reminder)
            }
            createGeoFence(latlng, key!!, geofencingClient)
        }
    }

    private fun createGeoFence(location: LatLng, key: String, geofencingClient: GeofencingClient) {
        val geofence = Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
            .setCircularRegion(location.latitude, location.longitude, GEOFENCE_RADIUS.toFloat())
            .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION.toLong())
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
//            .setLoiteringDelay(GEOFENCE_DWELL_DELAY)
            .build()

        val geofenceRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build()

        val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
            .putExtra("key", key)
            .putExtra("message", "Geofence alert - ${location.latitude}, ${location.longitude}")

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
                    ),
                    GEOFENCE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            } else {
                geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, pendingIntent)
            }
        } else {
            geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofenceRequest, pendingIntent)
        }
    }

    private fun isLocationPermissionGranted() : Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == GEOFENCE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (permissions.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "This application needs background location to work on Android 10 and higher",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (
                grantResults.isNotEmpty() && (
                        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                                grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    return
                }
                map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                onMapReady(map)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "The app needs location permission to function",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[2] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "This application needs background location to work on Android 10 and higher",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun removeGeofences(context: Context, triggeringGeofenceList: MutableList<Geofence>) {
            val geofenceIdList = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (entry in triggeringGeofenceList) {
                geofenceIdList.add(entry.requestId)
            }
            LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context).removeGeofences(geofenceIdList)
        }

        fun showNotification(context: Context?, message: String) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "REMINDER_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL"
            var notificationId = 1589
            notificationId += Random(notificationId).nextInt(1, 30)

            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!.applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_24)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(message)
                )
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                ).apply {
                    description = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
                }
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
    }

//    private fun scheduleJob() {
//        val componentName = ComponentName(this, ReminderJobService::class.java)
//        val info = JobInfo.Builder(321, componentName)
//            .setRequiresCharging(false)
//            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
//            .setPersisted(true)
//            .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
//            .build()
//
//        val scheduler = getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
//        val resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info)
//        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled")
//        } else {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed")
//            scheduleJob()
//        }
//    }

    private fun cancelJob() {
        val scheduler = getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
        scheduler.cancel(321)
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled")
    }


}
```

Comment: You have declared a param non-null which is supposed to be null/nullable. Could you share the code so that I can figure out the issue

Comment: share MapsActivity code, from logs it seems you are passing null to a non-null parameter.

Comment: In Kotlin this is not much different than in Java, since the JVM throws the exception. Since you did not provide the corresponding code which produces the error, my best suggestion would be reading about: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html (I could as well have close-voted for missing debug information).

Comment: `MapsActivity.kt` would be the least required to tell which variable definition is at fault.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed - it's not a generic question about nulls, it's about Kotlin inferring a parameter is non-null in a SAM conversion (one where that parameter is explicitly null-checked, too) when the library itself is passing nulls to it

Comment: I don't think this should be closed either - this happened to me after upgrading play-services libs, and is probably due to strict nullability annotations change - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_09_2021.

Comment: This crash is due to an internal bug of Play services in latest release, revert all your dependencies to the previous version listed for November 30th -> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_30_2021

Comment: I think you have to change the newer version com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1 (where these changes are made) to a previous version and com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.0 to a previous one

Comment: Google has fixed it, see: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_16_2021